# How to get the absolute path of a file in my project (and not of a file stored in a temporary folder)

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am using:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2);
- Apache Tomcat v8.0;
- a Web Dynamic project;
- a Java Servlet.

I have a JSON file stored in the `./WebContent` folder. I am trying to get the absolute path of the JSON file in this way:

```
ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();


    //String absolutePath = "/Users/kazuhira/Documents/MAC_workspace/lab2_calendario/WebContent/Database/Events.json";
    String relativePath = "eventsBackup.json";
    String filePath = sc.getRealPath(relativePath);

    System.out.println("(saverServlet): the path of the file is "+filePath);
    //System.out.println("(saverServlet): the path of the file is "+absolutePath);

    //File file = new File(absolutePath);
    String content = request.getParameter("jsonEventsArray");

    try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        System.out.println("(saverServlet): trying to access to the file"+filePath);
        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("(saverServlet): the file doesn't exists");
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("(saverServlet): file "+filePath+" created");
        }

        System.out.println("(saverServlet): writing on the file "+filePath);

        // get the content in bytes
        byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

        fop.write(contentInBytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();

        System.out.println("(saverServlet): events backup done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the file path reconstructed from the `relativePath` is:

```
/Users/kazuhira/Documents/MAC_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/lab2_calendario/testJson.txt
```

Why `String filePath = sc.getRealPath(relativePath);` generates a path on a temporary folder? In which way I can configure the context on the "real" json file (the same I create in the project)?

I suppose Tomcat is working in a temporary context, why? There's a way to tell him to use the same folder of the project?

Comment: why do you want to use an absolute path? all files kept under WEB-INF would be visible to your servlet if you use the url-pattern of "/"

Comment: when you run an app under tomcat-runtime in Eclipse, it exports and deploy the app into a temp dir, this is the case under an IDE, once you finished the app and exported it as WAR, then deployed it in a running Tomcat, the files will remain in the webapps dir, so this is nothing to worry about -i think-

Comment: @SampadaWagde This is a my workaround to use the same file from all entire application. For example, there is a JavaScript function that load many times the json file using AJAX calls (some times by GET method and sometimes by the POST method). There are some weird static file problems: despite in each ajax call the url of the json file is the same, the behavior of the application is strange, I think that the file loaded is not the same each time (some times load older versions of the file and sometimes not).  Im going crazy.

Comment: if you change the file in eclipse, right-click on the app listing in the server pane and select Deploy or Publish (can't remember), it will resync the contents betwen project folder and the temp folder

Comment: @SampadaWagde I have to use absolutee path to write on the file because fop.writes(...) need an absolute path.

Comment: Then save the path in a property file and write code to read the file from the property you define. That way, when the location changes, you won't need to change all your code. Just change the property value and restart server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by changing an option in your Server configuration in Eclipse

[image]

Select the second option in the radio button list :)

Comment: In my case the options in Serve Locations are blocked. I don't know because I can't change this option.

Comment: yes, you have to stop the server fisrt, then clean all webapp in it (right click on server line  then "Add and remove" then select your project(s) then click on remove) , now right click again and clean the server. Then that's good you can edit it

Comment: Yes, exactly: (1) stop the server, (2) close apps on the server, (3) publish and finally I can modify the configurations. Thanks!